# TypeScript return exact function infer type

Tags: typescript

I have this function:

```
const plainText = (text: string) => ({
  type: 'plain_text',
  text,
  emoji: true,
});
```

At the moment the inferred type return is:

```
const plainText: (text: string) => {
    type: string;
    text: string;
    emoji: boolean;
}
```

Is there a way to make it return like this with the type of `type` being `'plain_text'` as opposed to `string`? Or do I need to manually declare the return type?

```
const plainText: (text: string) => {
    type: 'plain_text';
    text: string;
    emoji: boolean;
}
```

I found I can do the following, but is this the best way to do it?

```
const plainText = (text: string) => ({
  type: 'plain_text' as 'plain_text',
  text,
  emoji: true,
});
```

I've got others like this:

```
const text = (text: string) => ({
  type: 'section',
  text: {
    type: 'mrkdwn',
    text,
  },
});
```

I'm trying to just create a bunch of functions to represent some repeated basic [Slack Block types](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/composition-objects#text) that I'm using so I can just pass them with eg. `plainText('hello')`. As I won't need to configure them, everything remains static and only the text changes.

The problem is when I call it against a Slack Client it required the typing to be exactly `type: 'plain_text'` instead of `type: 'string'`. [Type definition](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/blob/0456eb09985832cec5cbf10f150dced9a10fa92c/packages/types/src/index.ts#L59)

Comment: You can use `'plain_text' as const` but it would probably be better to define the type *outside* the function so the compiler can check what's returned against what's *supposed* to be (I'd recommend linting with e.g. https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-module-boundary-types.md to ensure this is done consistently).

Comment: I think you need to manually declare it. Type-inference is always a _best guess_ and has to infer your intent.

Comment: @jonrsharpe awesome, thank you! If I declared it outside, is there a way to declare only the `type`'s definition or would it be better just to declare it all?

I've got a few more like these which are a bit larger, so I'm just wondering if there's a way I could save a bit of time.

Comment: We'd need more context to tell you the best option. Are you trying to create types *discriminated* by the `type`, for example (so any consumer would know if the `type` is `'plain_text'` then there will also be `text` and `emoji`)? Please [edit] to explain how you're using these things.

Comment: Updated for more context :) Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is when I call it against a Slack Client it required the typing to be exactly type: 'plain_text' instead of type: 'string'. Type definition

You can declare a specific return type for your function rather than letting it be inferred.  My recommendation is that you make use of the types which are already defined by Slack when you are making factories for them.

```
import {PlainTextElement} from "@slack/types";

const plainText = (text: string): PlainTextElement => ({
  type: 'plain_text',
  text,
  emoji: true,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the `type` property to be the string literal, then you can use `as const` on that property to force typescript to treat it as the literal string "plain_text" rather than a generic `string` type:

```
const plainText = (text: string) => ({
  type: 'plain_text' as const,
  text,
  emoji: true,
});
```

What you did with `'plain_text' as 'plain_text'` is also fine though! They are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you! So many helpful suggestions here :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use generics:

```js
const plainText = <T extends string>(text: T) => ({
  type: 'plain_text',
  text,
  emoji: true,
}) as const; // small update

const foo = plainText('hello')
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgGwIYEswBUCmAPWBeGAHnRhykzABMIZoAnNAcwD4AKc3ALhnQEoY8zGKwDeAKBgwoATziZuAckSowAfQ5QFAGglSyOyZgC2IAFYpuUOgFdMOgL78kNUJCgBuMWNfQYAMxAQAXhkNCxcVgUAC0wEBBAFXiA)

In above case, TS will try to infer the type of argument.

Comment: The generic allows the `text` property to be seen as a literal string, but it doesn't sound like that's required.  It's the `type` where the literal is needed.

Comment: @Linda Paiste How would you do it without generic?  We still need literal type for `text`